# Could someone explain the difference between these two JS code snippets?

Tags: javascript

Could someone possibly explain the difference between these two code snippets? Is there any real functional difference? Is one superior than the other?

```
isIPad = function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
};


isIPad = (function isIPad() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
}());
```

Comment: 1) assign function itself; 2) assign returning value of function

Comment: Whenever you see parenthesis`()`, it means function is being executed and some value is being returned..Returned value could be anything..You may find [this](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/closures_in_javascript.htm) interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first variable will store a **function** that will return a boolean depending on whether the device is an iPad.

```
var thisIsAnIPad = isIPad()
if(thisIsAnIPad) {
  console.log('This is an iPad!');
}
```

The second variable calculates the **boolean** result straight away and stores it. You can use the value straight away.

```
if(isIPad) {
  console.log('This is an iPad!');
}
```

Neither method is objectively superior. They both have different use cases. For instance, if you just want to know at one point in time whether the user is on an iPad, then you can use the second option.

If it is a value you will need to recompute multiple times (maybe the user agent is changing?) then the first option is more preferable.

However, the second approach could be simplified to

```
isIPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
```

Which would be more memory efficient than either of the other options.